# How is this question unclear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How can Jor-El represent entire Kryptonian culture?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/217170/931)

This question has been closed as *"unclear what you're asking"*. May I know what is unclear about it so that I can improve it?

**Update:**
Edited the question to make it more clear. Please, let me know if it needs more improvement.

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Your question jumps from blood to culture and misses the link in between for why one connects to the other. It's not evident from the context you provide how culture fits into things. You have a bit of an exchange in the comments about it but that is *in the comments* not the question itself. Any pertinent information, which that is, should be in the question.

Then culture is a bit of a broad concept anyway so trying to discuss whether or not he represents it isn't rally that clear. To me at least it isn't really clear what you mean by *"How does Jor-El represent Kryptonian culture?"* because of that.

Personally I think your question needs expanding on, clarifying the link from the quote to your question and more specifically pinning down what you mean.

Comment: "Your question jumps from blood to culture and misses the link in between for why one connects to the other." ~> That's exactly the question. I can't see the link, but Brainiac saw a link. How?

Comment: @Lobo The point is how does blood imply culture which isn’t the point of the question as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay. Edited the question to make it more clear.